# Register an app in Azure AD for accessing the SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-online, azure-ad, connection

We have a desktop application that needs to be connected to the SharePoint list.

When a non-admin user tries they get an error that it needs admin approval.
[image]

So, we used the admin credentials to add the app to the AAD (Azure Active Directory) and consequently we can see it in the Enterprise Application group (so with the admin credentials we were able to connect to the sharepoint list, so the application works fine). Then, we created a security group, added our test user_account to it and assigned this security group to the Enterprise application, but still the non-admin (i.e. test user_account) login was unsuccessful. We also created a self-service for this app, with auto-approval (yes and no, both cases), but still no success. We also added the test user-account (i.e. non-admin account) as the owner of the app, but still no success. can anybody advise what we are missing here.

Please see the screenshots:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On the registered app in AAD, you need to go to 'Permissions' and use the Admin Consent button. Be careful with the permissions the app is asking for if they're 'Application' and not 'Delegated' permissions.

Comment: Thank you @Trevor, I have passed your response to our SP admin, will keep you posted as soon as I hear from them, thx

Comment: It has already been done, could you please advise, thanks